# Curiously Recurring Template Pattern with static and const private members

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template class:

```
template<typename T> class virtualCard
{
private:
    static int numCards;
    const int maxCards;
public:
    virtualCard(int);  //I want to manage all card construction from here
    virtual ~virtualCard();
    virtual void activate() = 0;
};
template<typename T> int virtualCard<T>::numCards = 0;
template<typename T> virtualCard<T>::virtualCard(int max) : maxCards(max) 
{
    if (numCards < maxCards)
        ++numCards;
    else
        throw std::logic_error("All these cards are on other people's hand, you can not draw any.");
}
```

Then, from my understanding, each instance of the template will have its own `numCards` and `maxCards`.

Then, I have this `card` class, which is an abstract class that only keeps count of the total of cards in the game.

```
class card : public virtualCard<card>
{
public:
    card();
    virtual ~card();
    virtual void activate() = 0;
};
card::card() : virtualCard(13) {} //there is a maximum of 13 cards in-game at any given time
card::~card() {} //don't do anything, it is all managed from the template class
```

But then I have a problem when I want to create a given card, for example:

```
class moveAnywhere : public card, public virtualCard<moveAnywhere>
{
public:
    moveAnywhere();
    virtual ~moveAnywhere();

    virtual void activate();
};
```

How should I call this card's constructor?

I tried `moveAnywhere::moveAnywhere() : card(), virtualCard(3) {}`

My intention was that creating a `moveAnywhere` card would create a `card` (so the `card` counter increases automatically by one. And additionaly I would have my own `moveAnywhere` static counter by calling `virtualCard<moveAnywhere>` with `3` as an argument (as the maximum of these cards is 3, oposed to 13 for `card`).

The problem is I get "Ambiguous access of `virtualCard`", I have tried to explicit change the constructors:

```
card::card() : virtualCard<card>(13) {}
moveAnywhere::moveAnywhere() : card(), virtualCard<moveAnywhere>(3) {}
```

But I still get an error.

Comment: Why are you inheriting from `card` and `virtualCard`?  Looks like you just need to inherit from `car`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Because I want to additionally have a static variable that counts how many `moveAnywhere` cards I have. That is why I inherit the template with `moveAnywhere`. If I only inherit from card, then I would only count how many `card`s I have.